# Orchard - Adding a Zone inside a Part (has a viewmodel)

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, zone

crosspost: https://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/461867

Here's the full scenario:
I have an EventItem content item which has an EventItem part containing all the custom fields (intro text, agenda, etc). I have another part attached to EventItem called tracks. The issue now is I want to add a Zone inside tracks so I can render fields from EventItem onto tracks via placement through the dynamic Zone. I know I could pull the data and render it inside the part, but I want it to be flexible and would prefer using placement/zones.

I know dynamic Zones are easy with alternates, like the one below on my **Content-EventItem.Detail** alternate:

```
@Display(Model.ImageArea)
```

However, my part uses a viewmodel so I need to predefine whatever properties/objects I use. I've read this blog as well but it doesn't work, or maybe I missed something:
http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2011/06/30/so-what-are-zones-really.aspx

Here's my full code (omitted irrelevant parts of code):

**Track Part Template**

```
@{
Func<dynamic, dynamic> Zone = x => Display(x);
}

<div id="Overview-Tab" class="track-tab">
   @Zone(Model.Overview)
</div>
```

**Track Part Viewmodel**

```
public class DisplayAllViewModel
{
    //public Shape Overview { get; set; }
    public object Overview { get; set; }
    public List<TrackItem> Tracks { get; set; }
}
```

**Placement for EventItem**

```
<Match ContentType="EventItem">
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
    <Place
        Fields_Sections="Overview:1"
        Parts_Tracks="Content:2.5.6" />
    </Match>
</Match>
```

The Sections field doesn't display at all when I use the Overview Zone.

Any piece of advise or information would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is not how placement and zones work: zones are defined in the Content shape, not in the child shapes below that.

In fact you're making things more difficult than they need to be. If you want to display a field inside your track part template, you can just do so:

```
@{
    var eventItemPart = Model.ContentItem.EventItem;
    if (eventItemPart != null) {
       @eventItemPart.NameOfTheField.SomePropertyOfThatField
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you may want to read this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2013/02/13/easy-content-templates-for-orchard-take-2.aspx which will show you how to flatten your template structure while maintaining the ability to display the original shapes.

Comment: appreciate the reply. yes, it's become very complicated and some retrofitting needs to be done. quick question, how do I render a part within another part?

I was already able to get the part with this below:
var speakerPart = Model.EventItem.Parts.Where(p => p.PartDefinition.Name == "SpeakerPart").FirstOrDefault();

However, when I try to render it through @Display(speakerPart), it only renders text. The same is shown whether I do it via the part template or the content shape template. How can I call I render it as how it should be (the display function in the speaker part's driver).

Comment: You never really render a part. You render a shape that has been emitted by a part's driver. A template is not the place to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Just add in the part @Display(WorkContext.Layout.Header)